# ifstream creates file if it doesn't exist

Tags: c++, linux, std

I'm having some trouble writing a Linux console app which reads apache logs.

I need to handle bash script arguments, the last one being a path to the log file.
My problem is that if the file doesn't exist, I would like to throw an exception.

But when I try to open the file in read-only mode, instead of failing it creates the file !

Here's the code :

```cpp
// logreader.h

#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdexcept>


class LogReader
{
    public:
        LogReader(int, const char **);
        virtual ~LogReader();

        // ...

    private:
        std::ifstream log_;
};

// logreader.cpp

#include <logreader.h>

LogReader::LogReader(int argc, const char ** argv):
    log_()
{
    log_.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit);
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
    {
        std::string arg(argv[i]);
        if (i == argc - 1)
        {
            try
            {
                log_.open(arg.c_str(), std::ifstream::in);
            }
            catch (std::ifstream::failure)
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("The file " + arg + " wasn't opened");
            }
        }
    }
}

LogReader::~LogReader()
{
}

// main.cpp

#include <logreader.h>

int main(int argc, const char ** argv)
{
    LogReader(argc, argv);
    return 0;
}
```

Script call:

```
jmcomets $ ./test -g -l
jmcomets $ ls -l
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jmcomets jmcomets     0 Nov 14 22:41 -l
```

Comment: Please create a complete, minimal program that demonstrates the error. See http://sscce.org for more information.

Comment: How do you know that the call to `log.open()` creates the file?

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. More to the point, when it is modified to compile, it doesn't demonstrate the error you are seeing. The problem you are seeing isn't with *that* code, it is with some *other* code in your program. That is why creating a minimal complete program, a la http://sscce.org/, is such a valuable technique.

Comment: There's a bug in the LogReader ctor: it should be `LogReader(int, const char **)`. When I fix that, the code still works like it should. I've even tested it with that funky filename `-l` and it works.

Comment: Okay, I fixed the question's code and tested it, it works as expected. The problem is effectively somewhere else, I'll try a debugger to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `failbit` in the exceptions flag for the `ifstream`:

```
std::ifstream log;
log.exceptions ( std::ifstream::failbit );
try {
    log.open ("test.txt");
}
catch (std::ifstream::failure e) {
    std::cout << "Exception opening/reading file\n";
}
```

[Source](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios/exceptions/)

I've tested, and `ifstream` will throw a `failure` exception if the file cannot be opened, e.g. file not found, no read permissions. It *will* open read-only.

Comment: I wish there were a way to globally enable exceptions on all fstream objects so that the constructor would throw an exception if it fails to open the file...

Comment: That's funny, it fails and throws an exception if the file doesn't exist for me.

Comment: Funny indeed... If I replace this snippet in my class' method handling script arguments, it creates the file and doesn't throw an exception. Otherwise in a small test file if I execute the same block of code, it fails and throws an exception. This may come from some weird initialization, I'll get back to you in a minute.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are opening an [`std::ifstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream) it is necessary to add `std::ios_base::in` (or any other spelling of the [`std::ios_base::openmode`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode)) according to 27.9.1.9 [ifstream.members] paragraph 4: The flag is automatically added by the call to `open()`. Note that an `std::ofstream` or an `std::fstream` would automatically add `std::ios_base::out` (27.9.1.13 [ofstream.members] paragrpah 3) or `std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::out` (27.9.1.17 [fstream.members] paragraph 3), both of which resulting in a new file being created if it doesn't exist (and there are write permissions, etc.).

If the code you posted creates a new file, the implementation of the standard C++ library is wrong: when only the flag `std::ios_base::in` is specified, the file is open "as if" using the open mode `"r"` with `fopen()` (27.9.1.4 [filebuf.members] paragraph 5). `fopen()` in turn doesn't create a new file when it gets an open mode of `"r"` (7.21.5.3 paragraph 3).

Answer (score 0):

Edit with something Linux compatible;

Try opening with fopen before writing. If the file DNE the `FILE` pointer will be null.

```
FILE * file;
file = fopen ("myfile.txt","r");

if (file == NULL)
   //throw if fopen didn't already.
else
    //do stuff with my file
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure `GetFileAttributesA()` doesn't apply to a 'Linux console app.'

Comment: Edited with something that does.

Comment: Well, if I'd downvoted earlier I'd take it back now. I wouldn't upvote this answer though; FILE* I/O isn't exactly the most awesome file API ever.

Comment: @bames53 Fair enough. You don't actually have to use it for reading the file though. You could just call `fclose` at the beginning of the else then read the file with a different API.

Comment: There's a posix function `stat()` (`_stat()` on Windows) that lets you check if a file exists.

Comment: @bames53 Well then why didn't you post that as an answer? I actually really like the FILE* I/O API. I pretty much used it exclusively when I was writing c++ in college.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify ifstream::in as a second parameter as:

```
log.open(arg.c_str(), ifstream::in)
```

You can also do:

```
std::ifstream log(arg.c_str(), ifstream::in);
```

and skip the call to `open()`